# Change font size of links/text in Bootstrap Paginator

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using the Bootstrap 3 pagination and I'd like to change the font size of link text in the li tags

using ..

```
<nav>
    <ul class="pagination" style="li {font-size: 50%;}">
        <li><a href="#">item #1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item #2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item #3</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

didn't work, I can't even seem to change sizes using other keywords like 'size' or 'height'/'width' (even without the directing the css change into the li tag itself in the stye tag).

what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the wrong way to add inline style

try with

```
<ul class="pagination" style="font-size: 50%">
```

however, the font size could be defined for the li tag or the a tag, so something like this would be more clean

```
.pagination li a {
    font-size: 50%;
}
```

Comment: works right, i also had to define the style in an overwriting css file, just by placing it in a stye tag just didn't pull it

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS to do it.

CSS:

```
.pagination > li > a {
    font-size:50%;
}
```